# Failed server start,

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran the following commands:

```
$> rails server
$> rails generate controller welcm indx
```

All I get are load errors for a bunch of ruby gems like sqlite3, bootsnap, etc.

I tried :

- reinstalling rails and ruby
- using `bundle install`
- killing spring

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    59: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    58: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    57: from /home/sindibad/Documents/RailsApps/kpp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    56: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    55: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    54: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    53: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    52: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    51: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    50: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    49: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    48: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    47: from /home/sindibad/Documents/RailsApps/kpp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    46: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    45: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    44: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    43: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    42: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    41: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    40: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    39: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    38: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    37: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    36: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    35: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    34: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    33: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    32: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    31: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    30: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    29: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    28: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    27: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    26: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    25: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    24: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    23: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    22: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    21: from /home/sindibad/Documents/RailsApps/kpp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    19: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    18: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    17: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    16: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    15: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    14: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    13: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    12: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    11: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    10: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
     9: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
     7: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     6: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     5: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     4: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
     3: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     1: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_database_name - /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so (LoadError)
```

I expect the server to start running for the 1st command, and for the required files to be created for the 2nd command.

Comment: I think.. you should be `generate`ing the controller before `start`ing the server.

Comment: i get the same error even tho i generate before starting the server

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't install NodeJS yet, try to install it

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

If you need to reinstall nodejs, you can follow the steps in the link below:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/786015/how-to-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: It didn't fix it. I think that i have ruined the gem loading paths or something.